# Reliably list users by location with a minimum reputation

Tags: support, reputation, data-explorer

I tried query 2803 ("Users by location, with a minimum reputation").

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/2803/users-by-location-with-a-minimum-reputation

I used my actual location from "Styrmansgatan, Stockholm, Sverige" (street, city, country in Swedish), as well as "Stockholm, Sweden" which the other guys are using as location, so there will only be one list for Stockholm.

I created a query listing us by gold medals

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/536036/local-gold-medals?CountryName=Sweden

It is two different lists. One for "Sverige" and one for "Sweden".

I can use my query for "Stockholm" and now it seems that I'm nr 3 in Stockholm according to gold badges.

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/629901

Comment: It's just a simple text search. There is nothing "to understand" about Sweden and Sverige being the same.

Comment: *'so we need to understand that Sverige and Sweden are the same"* Well, aren't they? I'm not sure who "we" is referring to in this sentence.

Comment: So where am I in the "simple search"? Nowhere. A country should have an id and not just a text that could by Schweden if you speak German in Sweden and then you get 3 different lists for Sweden.

Comment: `A country should have an id and not just a text ` Maybe it should - but it doesn't. Reliable querying for countries etc. does not seem to have been on SO's priorities list when they designed this, for better or worse

Comment: Also a proper geo system would not work for [those of us who reside elsewhere](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/52443/welbog)

Comment: The problem is that users can enter anything they darn well please into the "location" field, so there is no way for the system to have any "smarts" when processing this data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Geographically locating users was not a priority on Stack Overflow back when it was designed. Hence, the "location" field is a mere informational text field rather than a proper geolocation input field like it is on Stack Overflow Careers.

The feature would be fun (I'd *love* to see who else uses Stack Overflow on my tiny island, for example) and could help users connect locally - surely not a bad thing.

So far, though, it doesn't have seemed to be important enough for Stack Overflow to change.

Comment: Please look http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/536036/local-gold-medals?CountryName=Sweden I created a gold medal query where geography is a parameter

Comment: _"could help users connect locally - surely not a bad thing."_ Yay, now clueless people can also hassle me in real life and not only here!

Comment: @Epodax heh. I like to think the chances of that happening are pretty slim, though,  unless you opt to actually go to a meeting or something....

Comment: @Pekka웃 Never underestimate how far people are willing to go in order to get out of doing things themselves or not having to pay someone to do it.

Comment: @Epodax true, but as long as you don't give your street address and door number, there isn't really a point of contact (like there is when you publish your E-Mail address). There have been Stack Overflow meetups in the past, I don't think requests for coding help have been an issue there, they're mainly social events

Comment: @Pekka웃 But if I don't include my street address / flat number then how else am I going to know if I'm the best in the building?

Comment: @Epodax a serious problem indeed. Solution: use the flat number of the old hag downstairs who always looks at you funny when you climb the stairs. She'll be delighted to deal with the code requests of hapless Stack Overflowers.